# Showing Percentages on Donut Chart using Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graph, donut-chart

I have the following code to generate a pretty donut chart:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

size_of_groups=[12,11,30,3]

colors = ['#F92969','#FACA0C','#17C37B','#D9DFEB']

my_pie,_ = plt.pie(size_of_groups,radius = 1.2,colors=colors)

plt.setp(my_pie, width=0.6, edgecolor='white') # 

plt.show()
```

I'm not doing the method where you put a circle in the middle of your donut chart - this is because I need the interior of my plot to be transparent for another purpose.

Right now, the above outputs this:
[image: graph]

However, when I change the code to add the `,autopct="%.1f%%"` line, it breaks, but outputs a pie chart with labels anyway (though not a donut):

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

size_of_groups=[12,11,30,3]

colors = ['#F92969','#FACA0C','#17C37B','#D9DFEB']

my_pie,_ = plt.pie(size_of_groups,radius = 1.2,colors=colors,autopct="%.1f%%")

plt.setp(my_pie, width=0.6, edgecolor='white') # 

plt.show()
```

[image: graph2]

The error is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-ada97a3edee3> in <module>
     13 
     14 # Create a pieplot
---> 15 my_pie,_ = plt.pie(size_of_groups,radius = 1.2,colors=colors,autopct="%.1f%%")
     16 
     17 #,autopct="%.1f%%"

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

I'm unclear as to what this is, and I'm especially bamboozled that I'm having *some* output anyway, just without the hole in the center. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
my_pie,_,_ = plt.pie(size_of_groups,radius = 1.2,colors=colors,autopct="%.1f%%")
```

Adding `autopct` adds another return value to [plt.pie](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pie.html), so we need to assign it to something - hence the extra `,_`.

> **autotexts** : list
>
> A list of Text instances for the numeric labels. This will only be returned if the parameter autopct is not None.

**Output:**

[image]